# How to create empty vertical separation of tabular

Tags: tables

I know `\hline\hline` will create empty horizontal separation in `tabular`, how about empty vertical separation? The `||` seems not work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c||c|} \hline
    head1 & head2 \\\hline\hline
    cel1 & cel2 \\\hline
    cel3 & cel4 \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `||` makes a double rule with the same separation as `\hline\hline` is that not what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Your example produces

[image]

where you can see `||` makes a double rule, but `\hline` is always unbroken and cuts through it, perhaps you want

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c||c|}\hhline{|-||-|}
    head1 & head2 \\\hhline{|=::=|}
    cel1 & cel2 \\\hhline{|-||-|}
    cel3 & cel4 \\\hhline{|-||-|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about preserving the top/bottom line of the two parts: header, body. @david-carlisle

Comment: oh sorry you mean the outer `|` didn't notice those, just change `|=::=|` to `:=::=:` or in fact `=::=` would work as well